# Converting dataframe to list and dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dataframe:

```
      Region   Name    Price
0     ny       A         53.00
1     ln       B         52.23
2     ln       B         51.20
3     tk       C         50.50
```

I want to convert the data to a list within a list, and the name and price field into a dictionary. 
Name field is repeated, but I would like to get the unique values. Then assign the prices to the key.

Something like this: `[Region,{Name:Price}]`

For example:

```
[[ny, {"A": array([53.00])}],[ln, {"B": array([52.23 , 51.20])}],[tk, {"C": array([50.50]}]]
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to execute it?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Please add some code.

Comment: All I was able to create the dictionary first:
group = df.groupby('Name')
price_dict = group['Price'].unique().to_dict()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put Region, Name as a MultiIndex and export to_dict, something like that:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Region': ['ny', 'ln', 'ln', 'tk'],
    'Name': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    'Price': [53, 52, 51, 50]
})

# First, combined same values for Region/Name pair into a list
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Region', 'Name']).Price.apply(list).to_frame()

# Second, create a nice dictionary
df_grouped.groupby(level=0).apply(
    lambda df: df.xs(df.name).to_dict()['Price']
).to_dict()

>>> {'ln': {'B': [52, 51]}, 'ny': {'A': [53]}, 'tk': {'C': [50]}}
```

Comment: B has multiple values: 52.23 and 51.20. Would it be possible to assing more than 1 price?

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting as the answer (upvoting). Thanks!